# SQL query issues - how to find answer?

Tags: sql, qsqlquery, isqlquery

Tables:

- `PERSON` (ssn, Name)
- `Has_Visited` (ssn, city)
- `Belongs_To` (City, country)

Based on following information, create this question:

What is the name of the persons that have visited the city "London"?

Comment: Is this homework? (Important to give proper responses.) What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.Name from person p,has_visited hs 
where p.ssn= hs.ssn and hs.city= 'LONDON'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `in` operator:

```
SELECT name
FROM   person
WHERE  ssn IN (SELECT ssn
               FROM   has_visited
               WHERE  city = 'London');
```

Comment: I'm curious, why did you prefer this to join ? Is this a performance matter or just a preference ?

Comment: It's a readability issue - this query declares that it's selecting each person (no more than) once, not some combination of people and visits. Consider if the schema would be extended to list **when** a person visited a city, and allow multiple visits. A query using a join would return that person twice. This one would continue functioning properly.